# Is there a way to handle dynamically loaded selectors with clicks on pages in scrapy-playwright?

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright, scrapyd, playwright-python

I have a use case like this.
Suppose if I crawl a website abc.com using scrapy playwright
the page it loads are of 3 different types of pages  like

```
page1->#selector1 
page2->#selector2
page3->#selector3
```

and it changes dynamically
there is no guarantee which loads first.
I want to click on the selector based on which is loaded using
scrapy-playwright.

Is there a way to do this dynamically based selector loaded?

I tried using

```
PageMethod("click","#selector1"),
PageMethod("click","#selector2"),
PageMethod("click","#selector3")
```

and this is getting timed out because at that point in time #selector2 is loaded first on the page causing the operation to fail as the first method is PageMethod("click","#selector1")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the selector is visible and then you can click it?

```
if PageMethod("isVisible","#selector1"):
    PageMethod("click","#selector1")    
if PageMethod("isVisible","#selector2"):
    PageMethod("click","#selector2")    
if PageMethod("isVisible","#selector3"):
    PageMethod("click","#selector3")
```

I think you can usue the method isVisible, because scrapy_playwright support the same you have in playwright: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright#supported-methods

And of course, `isVisible()` is a supported method in playwrgiht: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-is-visible

Comment: Thanks for reply how do I add condition checks inside an array
beacuse scrapy accepts pagemethods like this in array what would the syntax be?

`playwright_page_methods=[
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "div.quote"),
                    PageMethod("evaluate", "window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"),
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "div.quote:nth-child(11)"),  # 10 per page
                ],`

Comment: I am not very familiar with scrapy_playwright, but sorry I do not understand the question of this comment, it does not look similar to the main question of the post